# ColorEditor does not show up in CollectionEditor

Tags: c#, winforms, workflow

I have one main property grid which has an element called MyCollectionOfColor where I have a collection of MyColor class which has properties name and color (which has UiTypeEditor as ColorEditor). So when the Collection Editor opens up and when I click on add button I have one instance created and I can assign a name, But the moment when I press on the dropdown icon of color property I don't see color editor pop up. If I remove attribute ColorEditor as a UITypeEditor then I can see the only dropdown of colors. And if I have color property on my main property grid it appears fine over there but not in the property grid of my Collection Editor. I am not sure what is happening here am I missing anything here?

Comment: A collection probably shouldn't be an array.  Use a List<T>, BindingList<T> or something.

Comment: Hi Lars, changing to list<T> does not help still color editor does not popup from modal dialog.

Comment: So its like the moment it reaches to  base.EditValue(context, provider, myColor) of coloreditor it returns back.